# JupyterLab not running Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-lab

I would like to report an issue I am having with JupyterLab. To do that I created a `test` environment by running the follwoing code in the terminal:

```
conda create -n ipywidgets-test --override-channels --strict-channel-priority -c conda-forge -c anaconda jupyterlab
conda activate ipywidgets-test
pip install --upgrade ipywidgets
```

So if I check the environments I get:

```
conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /opt/anaconda3
ipywidgets-test          /opt/anaconda3/envs/ipywidgets-test
```

Then from JupyterLab I check which environment I am in:

```py
import sys
print(sys.prefix)
/opt/anaconda3/envs/ipywidgets-test
```

And

```
which python
/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
which pip
/opt/anaconda3/bin/pip

python --version
Python 3.7.6

jupyter lab --version
1.2.6

jupyter kernelspec list
python3    
/opt/anaconda3/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
```

Now I am running a notebook in JupyterLab. As soon as I get to

```
import pandas as pd
```

I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

But if I run:

```
conda install pandas
```

The result is:

```
# All requested packages already installed.
```

And I if I check whether the package is installed, from the terminal, I see:

```
conda list
(...)
pandas 1.0.1  py37h6c726b0_0
(...)
```

But if I open a `jupyter notebook` from the terminal, the pandas module is imported without any issue.

Comment: Which kernel are you running in Jupyter Lab?

Comment: How can I find out?

Comment: Here's some documentation: https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/running.html

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand. The kernel looks like the name of the file I am running.

Comment: Do you have multiple environments configured? Did you install pandas in the correct environment? Did you install pandas in the correct install of python (macs have python 2 installed by default)? Did you install pandas using the anaconda prompt or the terminal?

Comment: @Emy, you could try `jupyter kernelspec list` as shown here: https://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kernels.html. This will show all installed kernels and their paths. Then you can inspect their settings, including the path to the Python interpreter. Looks like you have multiple Python environments, and Jupyter is configured to use some other environment where Pandas isn't installed

Comment: Thanks, running `jupyter kernelspec list` I get `python3    /opt/anaconda3/share/jupyter/kernels/python3`

Comment: @It_is_Chris Thank you for your help. I am new to Python, Jupyter Notebook and JupyterLab. I hoped that the information I provided was giving all the technical specifications. If not, how can I find the answer to your questions? To start, how do I know if I have multiple environments configured?  It may be. When I run JupyterLab from Anaconda, it works. In this case, I was creating a test environment to check out a problem I am having with interactive plots in JupyterLab.

Comment: @Emy you can do `conda info --envs` to list your environments. Activate the environment you want `conda activate base` then list the packages `conda list` See if pandas is there. if not install it using conda `conda install pandas`.

Comment: Thanks, while the `print(sys.prefix)` command was showing me that I was in `ipywidgets-test`, from the terminal I was indeed in the `base` environment. And once I moved to `ipywidgets-test`, `pandas` was missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the source of the issue (on Mac)

- I was starting terminal
- I was switching to the `test` environment
- After running a JupyterLab notebook in the `test` environment, I was getting an error
- To fix the error, I was opening another window in the terminal

***I hadn't realized that the new terminal window was back in the `base` environment!***

Apparently every time I open a new terminal window it defaults to `base`.

[image]

I switched to the `test` environment, where indeed `pandas` was not installed, and I was able to install it.